# ROS Driver on Fanuc R-J3iB?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to test the ROS driver on the Fanuc M6iB robot with an older R-j3iB controller. Some relevant information about the controller:

1. Core software version:  Handling Tool 6.4
2. Socket Messaging (SKMG), includes MSG_CONNECT, MSG_DISCO and MSG_PING: Installed
3. PC Interface (PCIF): Installed
4. KAREL (KARL): Installed (not sure about the version, but I can check)
5. ASCII Upload (ASBN): Installed.

Is it possible to tweak the ROS driver and recompile it for R-j3iB? Maybe somebody has tried this already and can help.

Regards,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381676/ros-driver-on-fanuc-r-j3ib?/) by [karpenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/77077/karpenko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A similar question from (quite) a few years ago would be #q173769. The OP there had a `V5.20` system, which turned out to be difficult to simulate, but *could* have worked after I made some changes. Unfortunately the OP never responded, so it didn't get tested.

I should still have that version somewhere, you could see whether it'll work.

If you could open an issue on [ros-industrial/fanuc](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc) we can discuss this over there, that'd be easier to track and relate to software changes.

I'll update this answer if/when we get things to work (and also in case we don't).

> Socket Messaging (SKMG)

Note: the requirement is actually for *User Socket Messaging*. There is a similar option (which may be called `SKMG` on older controllers), but that's not usable for Karel programs. Seeing as you mention `MSG_CONNECT(..)` et al., you probably have the required option installed, but I wanted to mention it.

---

Edit: post on the issue tracker: [ros-industrial/fanuc#325](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/issues/325).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0